# Explicitly wait for asynchronous action to complete?

Tags: mvvm, asynchronous, callback, wait, synchronous

I have the following utility:

```
class Worker
{
  public void DoWorkAsync(Action callback)
  {
    Action work = () => Thread.Sleep(3000);
    AsyncCallback asyncCallback = (result) => callback();
    work.BeginInvoke(asyncCallback, null);
  }
}
```

I use it like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var worker = new Worker();
  worker.DoWorkAsync(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed."));

  Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This will of course print `Hello world!` before `Completed.`, since the worker works asynchronously.

My question is how can I block my thread so it should wait until the action is completed, then move on.

I know I can do it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var worker = new Worker();
  worker.DoWorkAsync(() =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Completed.");
      MoveOn();
    });

  Console.ReadKey();
}

static void MoveOn()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

But since I have a bunch of cascaded async callbacks that should be executed one after the other (conditionally), I want them all to execute **synchronously**, so is there a more elegant way to wait for an async method that takes a callback as a param?

Note: Just to make sure, I cannot alter the behavior of the `Worker` class, its an external utility and I don't have access to its code.

### Update

In my particular scenario I'm trying to interact with user from the ViewModel and get responses from him. My code is executed in the view-model and there is a method controlling a chain of cascaded interactions, I want this method should decide whether to fire a certain interaction or not. I tried [SLaxs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254129/75500), and also tried [this](http://pastebin.com/tvxGxs7t) but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas on how to make the main method the only controller of the interactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), call [`Set()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) in the callback, and call [`WaitOne()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) to wait for the operation to finish.

Comment: That still doesn't solve my particular problem which isn't in my question. In my scenario I have a method that calls user to select one of the values on a list and generates a new list of the selected values of the previous prompt and so on. Now I tried your method and it blocks UI so the interaction doesn't popup. Please take a look at [**the code**](http://pastebin.com/BHu4EN7D) and see if you could please help me out.

Comment: Please look at the `OnTransactionSelected` method.

Comment: @Shimmy: I take it you're running on a UI thread?  That won't work; you can't run a blocking call on the UI thread.  You need to use callbacks (or  C# 5 `async`, which compiles to callbacks)

Comment: So how would you suggest me to do it efficiently in my scenario, I want the main method to take care of the notifications sent to user, the problem is this method is executed one by one, can I wrap this method so it should be async itself, not in the UI thread, I'll give it a shot, will call `OnTransactionSelected` asynchronously, the will wait in it.

Comment: I tried both `Thread` and `ThreadPool`, but it raised an `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception: `Invalid cross-thread access.`, the problem with using the callbacks is, that as you can see in [**the code**](http://pastebin.com/bHukM9sf), there is the main method taking care which interactions to fire, how can I do it if I work with callbacks? I want the callbacks to be agnostic to what's coming after them. How would you do it? Note: the code above is from my ViewModel.

Comment: Either use callbacks and do everything on the UI thread (but with more convoluted code), or use the ThreadPool, and use BeginInvoke to interact with the UI.

Comment: @Shimmy: Then use `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @Schabse, how? I tried [this](http://pastebin.com/ginXrFgj) and it doesn't work. Thanks for being so tolerant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7600/discussion-between-slaks-and-shimmy)